# How do you use workflow engine?

Tags: asp.net, workflow, workflow-engine

I know workfow engine is, but actually in our programming life, how can we get use of the workflow engine ?
How will workflow engine help us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows like Windows WF allow you to work in a logical process.  For instance, you can design a workflow process in Windows WF that drives the application.  So the application can work in a logical process from start to end based on the workflow.

Workflows often drive some business model.  FOr instance, an application may need to do these things in a logical order:

- User submit an application
- Notify a business user and automatically schedule a consultation with the applicant
- User submits a follow-up application
- User receives information packet

And so on...  I made that process up, so it's not the most practical, but hopefully it gives you an idea.  This is one type of workflow that can be done with Windows WF and other workflow engines, that can help your application utilize a workflow driven business process.

Workflows don't need a tool, but could be simply your process that the application uses to run through a series of screens or processes, so you don't actually need a tool to use workflow; the key component of workflows is the business process.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, and when we write the workflow script, how can we ask the user for information before we proceed to next phase ? there are different kind of methods to get information, how workflow can define this ? for example, maybe you user to just key in their comments, or you might need user to select a option from a list(how to predefine in workflow?) .  How workflow language can accomplish this ?

Comment: If speaking to Windows WF specifically, check out some online examples: http://odetocode.com/Articles/465.aspx, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/31/Windows-Workflow-Foundation.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163623.aspx.  Alternatively, you can simply structure your application to be business-process driven and not need to use a separate engine, and just structure your app to run that way.  It depends on how simple or complex the workflow is.

Answer (score 0):

you can write conditions or events in an xml and make it work on the fly. The parameters can be changed without changing the code.

Comment: so usually, what can we do by using workflow engine ? do you have an example for that which I think will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No disrespect intended, but if your looking at using Windows WF, wait for the next iteration with [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc896557.aspx), the current version has been essentially re-written to alleviate a lot of the pain points.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Brian's answer adding few more use cases.
Broadly we can classify workflows into two types: rule-based and cognitive.

[This article](https://searchcontentmanagement.techtarget.com/definition/workflow-automation) can provide good insight about workflow automation.

Few example of Rule-based workflow automation engines are: Zapier, IFTTT, Power Automate, n8n etc.

It is very difficult to automate cognitive-based tasks for example: classify customer issue automatically, check documents for completeness, content moderation, visual claim processing, detection whether social distancing been followed or not, signature verification etc.

Cognitive task automation require AI models, automate the task where we need human intervention.

Few example of cognitive-based workflow automation engines are: Levity and Obsei.

Disclaimer: I am creator of [Obsei](https://github.com/obsei/obsei): an open-source low-code AI powered automation tool.